# Decrease the width of b-dropdown-item bootstrap-vuejs

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

For some reason I am struggling to set a custom width size for `b-dropdown-item`-s in vuejs.
Below is my code.

```
<b-dropdown split split-variant="secondary-light" variant="secondary-light" :text="maxVersion.toString()" lazy
    :split-to="'/test'" @toggle="loadVersions">
    <b-dropdown-item v-if="loading" class="text-center" href="#">
        <b-icon icon="three-dots" animation="cylon" font-scale="2" />
    </b-dropdown-item>
    <template v-else>
        <b-dropdown-item v-for="version in versions" :key="version.version" :to="'#'">
            {{ version.version }}
        </b-dropdown-item>
    </template>
</b-dropdown>
```

I try to set max-width on each element but still for some reason the dropdown looks wide and not what I indented.

Below is what it looks like.

[image]

Does anybody know how to apply the style to make items narrower because it does not make sense to be that wide for some simple numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look accurately to `.dropdown-menu` CSS class. You will see this line of CSS in that class:

`min-width: 10rem;`

This line prevents your `ul` tag from decreasing. I provide a sample and quick code snippet in order to show the solution.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 1rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <b-dropdown text="All">
    <b-dropdown-item value="1">1</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
    <b-dropdown-item value="2">2</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item value="3">3</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```